# Trying to find getAdminStatus method

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, membership, roles

The SuperAdmin page in my web application has a method call to getAdminStatus() but I cannot find any occurences of this method when searching the entire solution. Is this method part of the .net 2.0 framework.

```
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="admin" Text="<%= getAdminStatus() %>"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

No it's not.

Is it possible this method is part of an external library (third party or otherwise)?